# Possible alternatives to PHP header_remove

Tags: php, http-headers

I am working on a website that is *not* on my own server, I do not have much (any) access to the server settings outside of the website SFTP.

The server previously ran PHP 5.21 and I used

```
header("X-Powered-By:");
```

To overwrite and remove the X-Powered-By header. This worked, but I have found that since the server was updated to PHP 5.6 that this no longer works, and the headers produced is:

> X-Powered-By:
>
> X-Powered-By: PleskLin

I didn't expect multiple lines of the same header, so I tried adding code to the page

```
header_remove("X-powered-by");
```

but the `PleskLin` header remains. Obviously the header is being added after PHP is processing the page, so bearing that in mind and it's a server I am really not familiar with.

Also running

```
header_remove();
```

Does not remove the `X-Powered-By` header but does remove other PHP set headers.

- Is there a way I can remove this header within PHP?
- How can I remove this header on the server, if it can't be removed by PHP (I can email the server owner and ask them to change a setting but they're not very tech' savvy in my few previous experiences with them).

Comment: If the header is set *after* PHP is done, there's literally nothing you can do. The web server has the last say about the returned response, and if it adds a header no matter what then that's it.

Comment: If your hosting company is not "tech savvy" it's time to choose a different one.

Comment: it's not *my* hosting company, @ThiefMaster, it's a clients

Comment: @deceze you may be interested in my answer. .htaccess removal of headers works for this.

Comment: @Martin I was under the impression that you can't do much with the server. Yes, if you reconfigure the server to not set/remove the header, then that obviously solves the problem.

Comment: I can only access the  HTML files area (via SFTP), the public html parts, the .htaccess is in the root html directory. I can't access PHP.ini or other wider settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that setting `header_remove` in the PHP and (strangely) also adding an `.htaccess` with the following does remove all `X-Powered-By` headers:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
```

To explain:
Original header given out is :

> x-Powered By: Plesklin

If I simply added the `.htaccess` removal code, the header became

> X-Powered-By: PHP 5.6.1

but then combined with the on-page `header_remove('X-Powered-By')` this cleared all values for that particular header.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do this is to ask the host to set expose_php to off in the php.ini file for you.

Comment: would that remove the header itself, as the header does not share the php version but the server it's the `Plesklin` ?

Comment: PHP won't set "PleskLin" as its header.